# CSS3 Ken Burns effects is not smooth in ie 11

Tags: css, transform, internet-explorer-11

```
img{
        transition-duration: 5s;
        transform: scale(1.0);
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }
    &:hover{
        img{
            transform: scale(1.2);
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        }
    }
```

This is the code I have used for ken burn effect in images, it works very fine in ff, chrome and safari. But I don't know what is the problem in ie 11.

Can you help me with it.

Comment: what is the problem you having? Like it got blurred or the fps drop?

Comment: actually effect doesn't works smoothly, it jumps or animation is kinda paused and played and paused and played.  )) i dont know a exact word to explain this thing :)

Comment: Give a try to `-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor` css property. **It will forces images to be scaled with an algorithm that preserves contrast and edges in the image, without smoothing colors or introduce blur. **

So far I have encounted IE animation rendering issue sometimes. The animation engine of IE quite weird. It is fast but broken sometime. This will drop all the fancy effects. Hope that it will help! :)

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same issue and fixed my problem by adding a small to rotation to the image.

```
transform: scale(1.5) rotate(0.1deg);
```

I came across [an article](https://gielberkers.com/how-to-fix-shaking-css-transitions-in-firefox/) offering this solution for a bug in firefox but it also works for the internet explorer like a charm.

Comment: thanks, works great for my animation that I use on a fullpage image (tested in IE11 and Edge v13, prefixed css added by autoprefixer):

`.ani-move {
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: move;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}

@keyframes move {  
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0.1deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this easy fix!